# i have cut my cement board too short for my shower walls

Tags: shower

I have cut my cement board too short for my shower walls; I need another 2 inches so it lines up right. Should I cut a 2 inch piece of cement board or go ahead and tie in the drywall for the remaining 2 inches?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What do you mean by "tie in the sheetrock"?

Comment: Photos or a sketch, please.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to speculate that you've set your cement board tight to the floor, and that it reaches two inches short of the height you'd like your tile to reach. I'm also going to guess that you haven't installed the drywall above the cement board.

Yes, you can bring your drywall down to the height of the cement board and lap the tile onto it. In fact, this is a more ideal scenario since it leaves you with a clean surface on which to terminate the tile. You'll probably want to finish the drywall and paint before setting the tile so that the grout or trim can lap over the paint for the cleanest lines.